# Can't find OpenGL ES performance detective in Xcode Version 4.5.2 (4G2008a) bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es

I recently discovered the existence of "OpenGL ES performance detective" in Apple's documentation but i'm unable to find it.

I found a lot of different possible locations in docs an forums but none was good in my case.

OpenGL ES performance detective is mentioned in [Xcode 4 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html) and none of the subsequent versions states its removal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe that the reason for this tool going missing within the Xcode package (in Xcode 4.4, you could find it within Xcode.app/Contents/Applications) is that its functionality is now handled within Xcode itself.

When you run an OpenGL ES application under Xcode 4.5, you'll see a little FPS counter running in the left bar. Click on that and you'll bring up a realtime performance readout from within your application. If you then click on the Analyze Performance button below that, you'll see a screen like the following:

[image: OpenGL ES performance analysis within Xcode]

This appears to have all the information that the old OpenGL ES Performance Detective used to.

You could also still download the 4.4 version of Xcode while it's [available on the developer center](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode), but I've had trouble getting the Performance Detective in that package to work with my iOS 6.0 devices.

Comment: Also, don't freak out if you don't see the FPS counter -- it apparently only shows up when connected to an iOS6 computer.

Comment: @racarate, It is possible to enable this feature for non iOS6 devices: in XCode, Product->Scheme->Edit scheme->[Select Run tab at left]->[Select Options tab at right]->Enable Performance Analysis->Always. This should do the trick.